# Cassandra Nested Data Model/Structure

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, nosql

I have problem with nested data model in my project.

Below are scripts for create table and user defined data type in my project.

```sql
// main table for keeping journey information
CREATE TABLE journey (
    journeyid uuid,
    journeyname text,
    createdate timestamp,
    journeyassetdetail LIST<FROZEN<assettype>>, // this is materials for journey
    journeylist LIST<FROZEN<subjourneylist>>, // any journey can be a sub journey in other journey (a journey can have one or more sub-journey)
    PRIMARY KEY (journeyid)
);

CREATE TYPE subjourneylist (
    action FROZEN<actions>,
    product FROZEN<products>,
    suborderjourney int,
    subjourneyid uuid,
    createdate timestamp
);

CREATE TYPE assettype (
    type text,
    file LIST<FROZEN<file>>
);

CREATE TYPE file (
    assetfileid uuid,
    filename text,
    url text
);
```

As you can see, there are 2 UDT on my journey table (assettype and subjourneylist) which mean it can be one or many sub-journey and assetdetail in a journey row. I design data model like this because I concern about READ performance, my developer need to get everything in one time connected to the database.

But look back into UPDATE, the problem is when I need to update somethings in any Asset or Sub-Journey, it means I have to apply the updated data to Journey (Main Journey table) which we don't know how to do that in easy way.

Right now, I have to use others tool or self-developed program to prepare a script to re-create whole journey again.

Do your guys have any suggestion with my data model or Do i have to reconsider another data model to support my read-write data.

Please feel free to give me an example or any suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K, this is better than making it bold

Comment: Is `type` field of `assettype` is unique ? When updating asset type  do you know the `journeyid` and `type` ? And for `subjourneylist` do you know the `journeyid` and  `subjourneyid` ?